# Form to Iframe Form reset

Tags: jquery, forms, iframe

I have a form that i target a Iframe with when submitted. Once the form is submitted I would like to reset the form to be blank.

Like what they talk about here:
[Form to iframe submission - how do you reset the form after file upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154260/form-to-iframe-submission-how-do-you-reset-the-form-after-file-upload)

```
<form action="functions/upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1" target="fileupload">

<iframe name="fileupload" frameborder="0" src="functions/upload.php" style="float:none; color:#FFF; display:none" width="100%" id="result" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

How is this implemented?

Comment: Please provide some code. You can call the javascript reset() function on the form to reset it.

Comment: That example you provided uses a server side page (upload.php) that the form is posted to. upload.php then returns javascript that will reset the form in the parent page.